# GWT: How to group related fields in a UIBinder form?

Tags: html, gwt, uibinder

What is the approach to group related fields in a large UIBinder form in GWT? The field group has a title and should allow optional selection of the entire group to appear/disappear or be enabled/disabled.

**UPDATE:** DisclosurePanel looks fine but does not mix well with custom CSS layouts and I do not want to use other widgetsets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [`DisclosurePanel`](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDisclosurePanel) what you're looking for?

Comment: I didn't expect a layout Panel for this. It really looks good but does not work well with our CSS layout. A widget that wraps HTML fieldset tag with a clickable legend and a collapsible content area would have been great. Although, I will accept your answer if nothing else comes up.